# How to deploy Apache Nutch -1.6 on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, nutch

I am using nutch-1.6 for crawling by triggering commands from terminal. I have searched over the internet and found that earlier versions of nutch like 0.9,1.0 come with war file which can be deployed on tomcat server but i could not find any documentation for deploying nutch 1.6 on tomcat.

Instead of triggering commands from terminal every time, I want to automate crawling system by deploying nutch on tomcat so that i can give command through a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Nutch 2.2.1 has REST based API to initiate jobs, retrieve data from db( configured store), stop job etc,

- Job manager API
- Db read API
- Configuration API

[Nutch2 Tutorial wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial)

[Running Nutch in eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse)

To start Nutch 2.2.1

```
./bin/nutch nutchserver 9000
```

After server successfully started we can access resources using rest requests

- Get detault configuration

   `http://localhost:9000/nutch/confs/default`
- Create new crawl job on server

  `http://localhost:9000/nutch/jobs` 

     **ContentType:** application/json

   **http method type:** PUT

  **Payload:**

  ```
    {
      "crawl":"123",
      "type":"crawl",
      "conf":"default",
      "args":
          { "class":"org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler", 
            "seed":"http://www.somesite.com", 
             "seedDir":"runtime/local/url/url.txt", "depth":2 }

    }
  ```